# cakephp 3 how to set custom css class for all bake view output

Tags: cakephp-3.0

hell , I'm new to cakephp 3 so please explain me step by step ,

i have my own layout i want to tell bake when you generate

```
<select>
```

do it like this

`<select class="myclass">`

for all bake ,  this is only example i want to apply this for **all html element** because i have my own custom  css , can anyone please tell me how i can do this ? i follow cakephp doc but i can't find how to do this trick . thanks .

Comment: I've never done that but I think this will help you a long way http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#customizing-the-bake-templates

Comment: Bake doesn't bake any `<select>` elements, it bakes form helper method calls, wich in turn create `<select>` elements at runtime. ps "nothing is there" is a pretty bland response, I don't think anyone gets what you mean.

Comment: i mean i want to change the default  output for bake views

Comment: @Mr.Mark Please checkout https://github.com/elboletaire/twbs-cake-plugin this is bootstrap 3 bake plugin you can refer this plugin to achieve your objective. Hope this helps you.